# ColdFusion not maintaining connection to Azure Data Warehouse

Tags: sql-server, azure, coldfusion

Our ColdFusion 2016 Enterprise server (Windows Server 2012 R2) is not maintaining connections to an Azure Data Warehouse. The first Azure query on a page takes a second or more to run. Subsequent Azure queries on the same page take a fraction of a second, e.g.:

```
test1 (Datasource=azureDev, **Time=3485ms**, Records=1) in D:\DW\dwtest\CF2016\bob\azureAdhoc.cfm @ 12:10:12.012
select count(*) cnt from dimpatient where name like 'smith%' and birthdate >'2014-02-01' 

test2 (Datasource=AzureDev, **Time=125ms**, Records=3) in D:\DW\dwtest\CF2016\bob\azureAdhoc.cfm @ 12:10:12.012
select * from dbo.dimPatientMergeStatus 

test3 (Datasource=azureDev, **Time=281ms**, Records=1) in D:\DW\dwtest\CF2016\bob\azureAdhoc.cfm @ 12:10:13.013
select count(*) cnt from dimpatient where name like 'jones%' and birthdate >'2004-02-01'
```

It seems apparent that CF is taking extra time to actually make the connection while running the first query on the page. We've tried with various queries and re-arranging their order and always end up with the same result.

We are connecting to Azure using the latest MS jdbc driver (mssql-jdbc-6.2.2.jre8.jar) and 'Maintain Connections' is checked. We first attempted to connect using the built in Microsoft SQL Server driver but kept getting this error:

```
Connection verification failed for data source: AzureDev2
java.sql.SQLException: [Macromedia][SQLServer JDBC Driver]Error
fetching requested database meta-data info.
```

We do not see this issue when we run the queries in SSMS.

Any idea what might be wrong?

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! You can format code and other stuff in your question, which improves legiblity. Also check https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask on best practices on this site. Cheers!

Comment: Slow network connection?

Comment: I work with Bob.  To be clear, when we did this work, we switched the order of the queries a few times and it was always the first one of the page request that was slow.  It also happened on every page request, and we were able to run them in rapid succession, every couple of seconds.

Answer (score 3):

> **How does ColdFusion Server manage database connections when there are client variables?**
>
> With ColdFusion Server version 4.5.1 SP1 and higher, when you store
>   your client variables in a database, your code connects to the
>   database only when a variable is set. This prevents unnecessary
>   database connections, for instance, in a case where you are using
>   client management, but no client variables are present in a particular
>   request.

https://helpx.adobe.com/coldfusion/kb/database-connections-handled-coldfusion.html

Comment: What does this have to do with regular JDBC database connections? The OP mentions nothing about client variables. CF4.5 is an ancient version, 18+ years old, that doesn't even use JDBC.

Comment: "Maintain Connections' is checked.", "Any idea what might be wrong?" @Ageax ok? also can you read? "and higher"

Comment: We are not using the database to store client variables so that wouldn't be applicable. But thanks for the idea..

Comment: @Ebuzer Taha KANAT - That still has nothing to do with regular query database connections. Read the link you posted.

Comment: @Ageax i really don't get your point when "Maintain Connections' is checked" CF uses connection pool right? so opening maintaining, closing, caching connections is servers responbilities.  And op says: "The first Azure query on a page takes a second or more to run. Subsequent Azure queries on the same page take a fraction of a second, e.g." this is expected result of connection pool with no inital connections. And the section i quoted is one of possible reasons why might be connection creation on call behavior.  Any objections Ageax?

Comment: @Ebuzer But we get this same connection behaviour with _every_ call to the page not just the initial call. e.g., run same page 5 seconds later get same result.

Comment: @BobKeleher what is timeout configuration of pool?

Comment: @EbuzerTahaKANAT - I mean the portion originally quoted above is talking about client variables, which are something different. They're handled automatically and don't always even use database. (So may want to update the answer to clarify).  However, if you are now talking about regular DSN settings, then yes, of course connection pooling can be a factor.  Though usually connetion pooling problems manifest by a slow query initially, followed by faster queries later.

Comment: @EbuzerTahaKANAT The pool uses the default values: 20 minute timeout and 7 minute checking interval.

Comment: @BobKeleher can you try connect to Azure Data Warehouse with the machine CF runs on but outside of CF with a mssql client of your choice to test if latency source is azure machines itself or not? if it is same problem with mssql client than there is no problem with CF.

Comment: @EbuzerTahaKANAT as mentioned earlier, we tried this is in SQL Server Management Studio and no latency was observed.

Comment: @BobKeleher Ram usage when CF working? Connections and threads uses ram so maybe latency is swap based can you check it? And appservers in general ram hungry beasts.

And if it is not that you should check compatibility of your driver https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/connect/jdbc/system-requirements-for-the-jdbc-driver 

incompatible drivers can cause problems.

Comment: @EbuzerTahaKANAT Plenty of RAM 100MB free, I'm the only user (this is a test machine). Using latest JDBC driver, mssql-jdbc-6.2.2.jre8.jar and recommended Java version 8. I've reported this as a bug on tracker.